# O que é Event-Dispatching Thread (EDT) em interfaces gráficas?

Tags: java, swing, awt, gui, event-dispatch-thread

Quando se está aprendendo a construir interfaces gráficas com `swing`/`AWT`, ouve-se muito falar sobre a *Event-Dispatching Thread* (ou `EDT`).  Apesar de já ter uma certa convivência com [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), confesso que não compreendo bem o que vem a ser a `EDT`. Sei que existe explicação na [**documentação(em inglês)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), mas não encontrei boas explicações e completas em português.

A partir disso questiono: O que é a EDT e como ela funciona durante a execução de uma interface gráfica construída usando swing/AWT?

Comment: Tem uma boa resposta aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217013/java-event-dispatching-thread-explanation

Comment: @Marconi eu vi, mas gostaria de uma boa resposta em português, infelizmente nem todos(onde me incluo) temos domínio do inglês, e tradutores as vezes retornam traduções confusas, pra quem não faz ideia do assunto, acaba atrapalhando mais ainda.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL;DR

É a única thread que pode manipular diretamente a interface gráfica para evitar problemas de concorrência. Ela fica num loop esperando por eventos que vem da tela (cliques, teclas, etc.) ou diretamente do programa e aplica todas as alterações sequencialmente.

## Motivação

Confesso que até ler um artigo citado na resposta da questão que o @Marconi deixou no comentário eu não sabia porque a EDT é do jeito que é.

Se você quer mesmo entender isso, faça um esforço e leia:

> [Multithreaded toolkits: A failed dream?](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kgh/2004/10/19/multithreaded-toolkits-failed-dream)

Em resumo: desenvolver um framework GUI multithreading, onde várias *threads* podem manipular os componentes da tela, não funciona na prática.

O autor argumenta que, a princípio, criar uma interface gráfica multithreading parece quase trivial, apenas uma questão de colocar os locks no lugar certo.

Entretanto, telas têm uma natureza que faz com que isso não seja tão simples: ela aceita eventos concorrentes opostos.

1. O programa altera a tela e a alteração é propagada dos componentes de mais alto nível na hierarquia até os de mais baixo nível. Por exemplo: Da janela, depois para o painel e depois para o botão.
2. Os eventos gerados pelo usuário vão dos componentes de mais baixo nível da hierarquia para os de mais  alto nível. Por exemplo: do botão, para o painel e do painel para o frame.

Tudo isso faz com que os locks não funcionem bem, gerando deadlocks e glitches com frequência.

O autor conta que foram colocados muitos esforços na época em que o AWT era multithreading e eles chegaram num tipo de beco sem saída. A solução foi fazer o que praticamente todos os outros frameworks de GUI faziam: mudar para um modelo EDT.

Ele ainda argumenta que existem implementações de GUI multithreading, porém elas só funcionam bem se as pessoas que desenvolvem a GUI forem as mesmas que desenvolvem o framework, pois isto exige conhecimento específico e detalhado do modelo. Porém, num framework de propósito geral feito para uso em larga escala, isso nunca iria funcionar bem.

Portanto, no modelo usando EDT, as alterações na GUI são feitas todas usando uma única thread (*single threaded*) gerenciada pelo framework e quando as outras threads (como a thread principal do programa) querem realizar alguma alteração, elas devem disparar um evento para a thread do AWT.

Uma das formas de fazer isso é usando `invokeLater`, porém dentro de manipuladores de eventos (*listeners*) isto não é necessário porque eles executam dentro da thread do AWT, o que também implica que qualquer processamento demorado dentro da EDT bloqueia todo o programa.

Comment: Ótima explicação!