# Atualizar JTable após cada alteração de dados em uma célula

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swingworker

Estou usando java [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) onde tenho uma janela e nela uma `JTable`.

Executo um método onde lerá os dados desta `Jtable` e atualizará uma coluna, célula a célula, desta `Jtable`. O problema é que ele executa o método normalmente,rodando o looping, mas atualiza a coluna(todas as células) somente no final. Gostaria que atualizasse a célula linha a linha e não tudo somente no final.

Segue código:

```
 private void BtnEnviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


        SMSMultiploBean smsb = new SMSMultiploBean();
        SMSMultiploDAO smsd = new SMSMultiploDAO();

        int i;
        int linha = 0;
        int totenviados = 0;

        for(i = 0;i<TblDadosSMS.getModel().getRowCount();i++){


            smsb.setDdd((String) TblDadosSMS.getValueAt(linha, 4));
            smsb.setTelefone((String) TblDadosSMS.getValueAt(linha, 5));
            smsb.setMensagem((String) TblDadosSMS.getValueAt(linha, 6));
            smsb.setLinha((int)TblDadosSMS.getValueAt(linha,8));


            Date data= JData.getDate();
            Format ff = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
            String datastring = ff.format(data);

            smsb.setData(datastring);


                try {            

                    String retorno = smsd.EnviaSms(smsb);

                     //retorno falando se o SMS foi enviado ou não

                    TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(retorno, i, 7);

                    //TblDadosSMS.firePropertyChange(retorno, i, i);

                    Pbar.setMinimum(0);
                    Pbar.setMaximum(Integer.parseInt((LblTotal.getText())));
                    Pbar.setValue(i+1);



                    if (retorno.equals("Enviado")){
                      totenviados += 1;
                      LblEnviados.setText(Integer.toString(totenviados));
                    }

                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(FrmSMSSimultaneo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro: "+ex);
                 }
                     linha++;


       }   


    }
```

Janela antes de executar o método:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Janela depois de executar o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo código para popular tabela:

```
private void CarregaDadosPlanilha() throws SQLException, IOException, ParseException, Exception {

    ExcelBean eb = new ExcelBean();
    ExcelDao ed = new ExcelDao();


    //data convertida para String
    Date data = JData.getDate();
    SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
    String novadata = formatador.format(data);  


    //conversão String para date
    String texto = novadata;  
    String formato = "dd/MM/yyyy";  
    Date dataobjeto = new SimpleDateFormat(formato).parse(texto);

    //System.out.println("Data tratada date: "+dataobjeto);  

    eb.setData(dataobjeto);

    List<ExcelBean> ListaDadosPlanilha = new ArrayList<ExcelBean>();

           // ListaDadosPlanilha = ed.CarregaExcel(eb);
     ListaDadosPlanilha = ed.LeExcel(eb);

            DefaultTableModel tbm = (DefaultTableModel) TblDadosSMS.getModel();

            //zera as linhas da tabela
            for (int i = tbm.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                tbm.removeRow(i);
            }
            int i = TblDadosSMS.getRowCount();
            /*
             * preenche a tabela
             */
               for (ExcelBean eb2 : ListaDadosPlanilha) {
                tbm.addRow(new String[1]);

                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getNome(), i, 0);
                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getServico(), i, 1);


                //data convertida para String
                Date dataexcel = JData.getDate();  
                SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
                String datastring = f.format(dataexcel);  

                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(datastring, i, 2);
                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getHorario(), i, 3);
                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getDdd(), i, 4);
                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getTelefone(), i, 5);

                eb2.setMensagem("Prezado(a): "+eb2.getNome()+
                    " , nao se esqueca que tem o servico: "+eb2.getServico()+" marcado para: "+novadata+
                    " as: "+eb2.getHorario());


                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getMensagem(), i, 6);


                TblDadosSMS.setValueAt(eb2.getLinha(),i,8);

                System.out.println("Linha célula form: "+eb2.getLinha());


              //System.out.println("linha jtable: "+eb2.getLinha());



                i++;
            }

               LblTotal.setText(Integer.toString(tbm.getRowCount()));
}
```

Comment: Você está usando um TableModel próprio ou está usando defaultTableModel nessa tabela?

Comment: Rodrigo, quando você criar uma pergunta e precisar complementar ela, clique em [edit] na pergunta e adicione diretamente as informações nela. O campo abaixo é para respostas.

Comment: Desculpe Diego, ainda estou pegando o jeito.

Comment: Desculpe pela intromissão, mas você já tentou utilizar um método que envia um por um, lendo esse um em seguida após a alteração e deixar automaticamente alterar (update) de um segundo método e assim sucessivamente até terminar todos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque você está executando o loop e incrementando o progresso dentro do [Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115168/28595),  e essa `Thread` vai executar todo o código que estiver nela antes de atualizar o container(JFrame, Jpanel, etc) e seus componentes.

Para atualizar a tabela e o progresso a cada linha, você precisa a atualizar o `TableModel` em uma `Thread` paralela, e a melhor forma de fazer isso junto com a EDT é usando [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Elaborei um exemplo simples somente pra demonstrar o funcionamento do `SwingWorker` com a EDT, está comentado os principais trechos referente ao funcionamento do progresso:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgressWithSwingWorker extends JFrame {

    private JButton btnChecar;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JScrollPane ScrollPane;
    private JTable tabela;

    public ProgressWithSwingWorker() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        ScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        btnChecar = new JButton();
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();

        String[] columns = {"coluna 1", "coluna 2", "coluna 3", "coluna 4"};
        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 3) {
                    return Boolean.class;
                } else {
                    return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        };

        tabela = new JTable(model);

        ScrollPane.setViewportView(tabela);
        btnChecar.setText("Checar");
        //A "mágica" acontece na classe ChecarComSwingWorker
        btnChecar.addActionListener(new ChecarComSwingWorker());

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(ScrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(btnChecar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ProgressWithSwingWorker().setVisible(true));
    }

    class ChecarComSwingWorker implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            final int totalRows = tabela.getModel().getRowCount();
            progressBar.setMaximum(totalRows);
            progressBar.setMinimum(0);
            //passei parametros para facilitar o entendimento
            //- o primeiro é o retorno do doInBackground(não foi necessario uso neste exemplo)
            //- o segundo é o tipo do valor usado entre o publish e o process
            SwingWorker<Object, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Integer>() {

                //este método é que executa em uma Thread paralela
                //todo processamento pesado que deve ser executado
                //fora da EDT, deve ser executado aqui 
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
                        try {
                            Boolean status = (Boolean) tabela.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
                            status = status == null ? true : !status;
                            tabela.getModel().setValueAt(status, i, 3);
                            //este método é que atualiza a barra de progresso
                            //passando cada iteração para o método process
                            publish(i);
                            Thread.sleep(400);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                //este método é que recebe o que é passado no publish
                //e atualiza a barra de progresso na EDT
                @Override
                protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                    int valueRecent = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                    progressBar.setValue(valueRecent + 1);
                }

                //só é executado quando o doInBackground termina
                //o processamento
                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    progressBar.setValue(0);
                }
            };

            worker.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

E o resultado é:

[image: gif de execução do código]

Segue abaixo alguns links relativos ao uso do `SwingWorker`:

[11.5 - Dificuldades com Threads e concorrência - Caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/apendice-mais-swing-e-recursos-avancados/#11-5-dificuldades-com-threads-e-concorrencia)

[Trabalhando com SwingWorker em Java - DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-swingworker-em-java/29331)

[Capturar exceções na execução do swingworker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124867/capturar-exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-na-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-swingworker/124869#124869)

[Passar a execução de um determinado método para outro como argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120325/passar-a-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-determinado-m%C3%A9todo-para-outro-como-argumento)

Comment: Diego, ao escrever TblDadosSMS.getModel().fireTableDataChanged(); o NETBEANS identifica como erro.  Estou usando estas bibliotecas  "import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;"

Comment: segui o tutorial do devmedia e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado. Problema resolvido

Comment: @RodrigoStortideOliveira se a resposta lhe ajudou, seria interessante marcá-la como aceita, assim,servirá de referencia para outros usuarios. :)