# Capturar exceções na execução do swingworker

Tags: java, swing, exceção, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

Estou utilizando `SwingWorker` para executar um método que pode lançar exceções.
Mesmo forçando, a exceção não é capturada pelo *try-catch*. Como posso solucionar este caso?

```
try {
    (new SwingWorker < Void, Void > () {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
            // Pode lançar exceções
            Controller.getInstance().save(d);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {}
    }).execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocorreu um erro:n" + ex.getMessage(), "Erro ao salvar", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não lança pois o [`doInBackground`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground()) executa em uma Thread à parte do [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) (EDT). É graças a isso que você pode efetuar operações complexas ou pesadas sem que a interface fique travada aguardando a conclusão da tarefa.

Para capturar possíveis exceções lançadas dentro do `doInBackground`, você pode chamar o método [**`get()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) dentro no método `done()`(que é executado após o fim da execução paralela), e capturar a exceção dentro deste método, pois o `get()` retorna o tipo de dado que você definiu como retorno no `doInBackground`(no seu caso, seria `Void`) ou uma exceção do tipo `InterruptedException`(se a Thread for interrompida) ou `ExecutionException`(se foi lançada uma exceção dentro da execução do doInBackground), e no `done()` a execução volta a ser na Thread do EDT:

```
(new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        // Pode lançar exceções
        Controller.getInstance().save(d);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try{
            get();
        }catch(ExecutionException e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ocorreu um erro:\n" + ex.getMessage(), "Erro ao salvar", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            //catch opcional se quiser tratar a interrupção
            // da thread da tarefa paralela
        }
    }
}).execute();
```

Nesta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231306/5524514) tem uma explicação excelente sobre exceções no `SwingWorker`, vale a pena dar uma lida.