# Mostrar JProgressBar enquanto realiza conexão com banco de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, swing

Tenho uma aplicação desktop em java com netbeans fazendo a conexão por JDBC, e estou com uma classe que faz conexão com banco de dados e me retorna alguns itens que lá estão armazenados. Gostaria de exibir um `progressBar` enquanto a conexão com banco é estabelecida, alguém tem algum exemplo de como posso fazer isso?
Esse é o método que executo e congela a tela:

```
public ResultSet informacoesDiarias(String dataInicial,String dataFinal) {
    conn = new ConexaoBD().getConexao();

    String sql = "SELECT * from producaoDiara WHERE dataProducao BETWEEN '" + dataInicial +" 'AND' " +dataFinal+ "'";
    try {

        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Erro do capiroto:"+ex.getMessage()+"\ntipo:"+ex.getClass());
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Gostaria que quando eu chamasse esse método a barra de progresso aparecesse.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como usar JProgressBar em classes de comparação de ArrayList?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130504/28595) e [Atualizar JTable após cada alteração de dados em uma célula](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119137/28595)

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Antes de tudo, adicione um [mcve] do seu código para que seja possivel analisar a dúvida. Veja os links acima também.

Comment: Leia isso: [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Comment: obrigado @diegofm pelas dicas