# JProgressBar carregando em tempo real

Tags: java, swing

Parece bobo, mas não sei porque não está incrementando o JProgressBar() da minha aplicação Java Swing. Segue código abaixo:

```
public void executar() {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("Z:\");
        fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        v_Caminho.setText(file.getAbsolutePath()); //campo texto simples

        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                v_Progresso.setMaximum(fileSize); //JProgressBar()

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= fileSize; i++) {
                        fileSize = (fileSize * 100) / 1024;

                        v_Progresso.setValue(fileSize);
                        v_Progresso.setStringPainted(true);

                        sleep(300);

                        System.out.println("Restam: " + fileSize + " bytes para o carregamento.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Ele calcula certinho o tamanho do arquivo e vai printando no "*sout*" o restante para o carregamento. Eu preciso fazer esse restante virar **incremento** no JProgressBar() e não está funcionando. O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tem que usar SWINGWORKER, veja outra resposta q usa essa solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119137/164151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma curiosidade, não seria mais facil setar o valor de jprogress com o `i`?

o `for` poderia ser assim:

```java
for (int i = fileSize; i >=0; i--) {

    v_Progresso.setValue(i);
    v_Progresso.setStringPainted(true);

    sleep(300);

    System.out.println("Restam: " + i+ " bytes para o carregamento.");
}
```

Vamos pensar só um pouco nesse código a seguir:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("Z:\\");
        fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        v_Caminho.setText(file.getAbsolutePath()); //campo texto simples

        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                v_Progresso.setMaximum(fileSize); //JProgressBar()
                v_Progresso.setMinimum(0);
                System.out.println("Tamanho do fileSize inicial: "+fileSize);
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= fileSize; i++) {
                        fileSize = (fileSize * 100) / 1024;
                        System.out.println("FileSize: "+fileSize+ "\t i = "+i);
                        v_Progresso.setValue(fileSize);
                        //v_Progresso.setStringPainted(true);

                        sleep(1000);

                        System.out.println("Restam: " + fileSize + " bytes para o carregamento.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
        System.out.println("fim");
```

digamos que temos um arquivo de 356352b inicial..
então no primeiro for (i==0) ele valerá 34800
depois i == 1 valerá 3398
depois i == 2 331
depois i == 3 32
i ==4 3
e vai finalizar com 3 o fileSize,

vamos analizar a primeira interação com o for.. o i ==0

na entrada temos 356352b mas na primeira interação com o for ele ja passa a valer 9,76% do valor total (34800).. e a cada repetição esse numero só cai...
chegando a representar 0 bem rápido.. como podemos ver o valor 3398 já é bem pequeno comparado com o 34800 inicial.. imagina 331 e 32...

Comment: Então amigo, eu já havia feito dessa forma. O problema é que ele vai fazer uma regressão muito imensa. Eu preciso fazer o JProgressBar setar o value dele de acordo com o quanto resta "realmente" para ser carregado. Por exemplo: fileSize = 9Mb. Preciso fazer a ProgressBar assumir esse Maximum e calcular o decremento. Esse está sendo o problema. Ele chega a carregar 12% iniciais depois volta para o 0%. Enquanto isso, o sout dispara perfeitamente:

Restam: 893762 bytes.
Restam: 87281 bytes.
Restam: 8523 bytes.
Restam: 832 bytes.
Restam: 81 bytes.
Restam: 7 bytes.
Restam: 0 bytes.

Comment: Compreendo... Vou analisar melhor o meu código, então. Creio que eu tenha feito algum procedimento incorretamente até chegar nesse FOR como sugeriu. Realmente não tinha funcionado. Então fiz algo errado... Retornarei com um status. Obrigado!