# Como fechar uma tela após abrir outra?

Tags: java, swing

Estou com problemas para fechar tela, estou programando no eclipse.

Ao executar, o programa é aberto e a janela de Login aparece, quando o usuário colocar o código e senha correta, aparece uma mensagem para avisar que você obteve acesso, e então uma segunda segunda janela deve ser aberta. Até aqui tudo bem, mas estou com problemas para fechar apenas a janela de Login quando a segunda janela é aberta.

Esse é o código da tela de login.

```
package teste;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel jPanel, jp1, jp2, jp3;
    private JLabel lbSenha, lbCod;
    private JTextField jtfSenha, jtfCod;
    private JButton jbLogar, jbSair;
    private static TesteCon tc;
    private String janStat;

    Login(){
        jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp3 = new JPanel();

        lbSenha = new JLabel("Senha:");
        lbCod = new JLabel ("Codigo:");

        jtfSenha = new JTextField(10);
        jtfCod = new JTextField(10);

        jbLogar = new JButton("Logar");
        jbLogar.addActionListener(this);
        jbSair = new JButton("Sair");
        jbSair.addActionListener(this);

        jp1.add(lbCod);
        jp1.add(jtfCod);
        jp2.add(lbSenha);
        jp2.add(jtfSenha);
        jp3.add(jbLogar);
        jp3.add(jbSair);

        jPanel.add("North",jp1);
        jPanel.add("Center",jp2);
        jPanel.add("South",jp3);

        setTitle("Login");
        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Login log = new Login();
        tc = new TesteCon();
    }

    public void limpar(){
        jtfCod.setText("");
        jtfSenha.setText("");

    }

    public String getJanStat() {
        return janStat;
    }

    public void setJanStat(String janStat) {
        this.janStat = janStat;
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
        if(evento.getSource() == jbLogar){
            String js;
            tc.acesso(jtfCod, jtfSenha);
            js = getJanStat();
            if (js == "fechar"){
                this.dispose();
            }
            limpar(); 

        }

        if(evento.getSource() == jbSair){
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }   
}
```

Esse é o código da classe de conexão.

```
package teste;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TesteCon{
   private String driver,url;
   Connection conexao;

   Statement stm;
   ResultSet rs;
   Login log;

   public TesteCon(){
    //driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
   driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:guilherme/1997@//localhost:1521/XE";
    conecta(driver,url);
}
public void conecta(String driver, String url){
    try{
    // carrega o driver da ponte jdbc-odbc
    Class.forName(driver);
    // abre conexao com o banco de dados
    conexao=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Conexão executada com sucesso");
    //conexao.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException SqlExc){
        System.out.println("Erro de SQL!");
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException exc){
        System.out.println("Classe não encontrada!");
    }
    }   

 public void acesso(JTextField jtfCod, JTextField jtfSenha){

    try{
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement stm = conexao.createStatement();
    conecta(driver, url);
    String s, statusLog="";

    String sql = "select * from usuario";
    rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
    //rs.next();
    while (rs.next()) {
        if(jtfCod.getText().equals(rs.getString("codigo")) 
                && jtfSenha.getText().equals(rs.getString("senha"))){
            statusLog = "on";
            break;
        }
        else{
            statusLog = "off";
            }
    }
    //nesse if eu mostro a msg de acesso permitido, abro a segunda janela e mudo o valor de janStat para poder fechar a jenela.
    if(statusLog=="on"){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Acesso permitido");

        janela2 jan = new janela2();
        jan.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));// aqui foi apenas um teste para um Label da segunda janela.
        log.setJanStat("fechar");


        }
    else if(statusLog=="off"){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Acesso negado");

        }
    //criei esse else apenas para testes.
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ELSE");

        }


    conexao.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
    }
}


public  static void main(String args[]){
        TesteCon ins=new TesteCon();
    }
}
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não está funcionando?". Se for uma JFrame, dispose resolveria o problema. A janela não fecha mesmo com dispose ou está fechando a aplicação toda? Pode postar um [mcve] dessa janela de login?

Comment: Coloquei os códigos completos.

Comment: Leitura adicional: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários problemas nesse seu código, você está misturando as camadas de telas(views) com camadas de comunicação com o banco(models), está delegando coisas a sua classe de conexão que ela não deveria nem fazer idéia que existe. Em swing, deve-se iniciar a aplicação dentro da [event-dispatch-thread](/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread)(os motivos você pode ver [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115710/28595) e [nesta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) citada pelo [@VictorStafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa)), então eu fiz esta alteração no código também.

Para resolver o problema sem ter que refatorar o código inteiro, adaptei seu método `acesso` para que ele receba apenas as strings contendo o login e senha, valide e retorne se houve sucesso através de um booleano. Assim você restringe seu uso, que é apenas checar se o login é válido.

Na sua classe de login, você deve receber o retorno e a partir dai tomar uma ação, ou seja, se o retorno foi verdadeiro, você abre a nova janela e chama o dispose da janela atual de login, se for falso você exibe a mensagem de login invalido e limpa os campos.

Segue as duas classes alteradas:

Classe Login como deveria ser:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel jPanel, jp1, jp2, jp3;
    private JLabel lbSenha, lbCod;
    private JTextField jtfSenha, jtfCod;
    private JButton jbLogar, jbSair;
    private TesteCon tc;
    private String janStat;

    Login() {
        jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp2 = new JPanel();
        jp3 = new JPanel();

        lbSenha = new JLabel("Senha:");
        lbCod = new JLabel("Codigo:");

        jtfSenha = new JTextField(10);
        jtfCod = new JTextField(10);

        jbLogar = new JButton("Logar");
        jbLogar.addActionListener(this);
        jbSair = new JButton("Sair");
        jbSair.addActionListener(this);

        jp1.add(lbCod);
        jp1.add(jtfCod);
        jp2.add(lbSenha);
        jp2.add(jtfSenha);
        jp3.add(jbLogar);
        jp3.add(jbSair);

        jPanel.add("North", jp1);
        jPanel.add("Center", jp2);
        jPanel.add("South", jp3);

        setTitle("Login");
        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Login log = new Login();
            }
        });
    }

    public void limpar() {
        jtfCod.setText("");
        jtfSenha.setText("");

    }

    public String getJanStat() {
        return janStat;
    }

    public void setJanStat(String janStat) {
        this.janStat = janStat;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
        if (evento.getSource() == jbLogar) {
            String js;
            tc = new TesteCon();
            boolean logado = tc.acesso(jtfCod.getText(), jtfSenha.getText());
            if (logado) {

                //aqui você troca pela chamda da sua outra tela
                SuaNovaJanela novaJan = new SuaNovaJanela();
                novaJan.setVisible(true);

                this.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login inválido");
                limpar();
            }
        }

        if (evento.getSource() == jbSair) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Classe TesteCon:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TesteCon {

    private String driver, url;
    Connection conexao;

    Statement stm;
    ResultSet rs;
    Login log;

    public TesteCon() {
        //driver="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:guilherme/1997@//localhost:1521/XE";
        conecta(driver, url);
    }

    public void conecta(String driver, String url) {
        try {
            // carrega o driver da ponte jdbc-odbc
            Class.forName(driver);
            // abre conexao com o banco de dados
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Conexão executada com sucesso");
            //conexao.close();
        } catch (SQLException SqlExc) {
            System.out.println("Erro de SQL!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
            System.out.println("Classe não encontrada!");
        }
    }

    public boolean acesso(String jtfCod, String jtfSenha) {
        boolean logou = false;
        try {
            ResultSet rs;
            Statement stm = conexao.createStatement();
            conecta(driver, url);

            String sql = "select * from usuario";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            //rs.next();
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (jtfCod.equals(rs.getString("codigo"))
                        && jtfSenha.equals(rs.getString("senha"))) {
                    logou = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            conexao.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return logou;
    }
}
```

Há outros problemas com as duas classes, mas não cabe comentar aqui para não estender demais a resposta saindo do foco da pergunta.

Comment: Agora esta funcionando, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @GuilhermeSouza que bom que funcionou :D você pode marcar a resposta como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda. Assim, ela servirá de referencia para outras pessoas.