# Button travado no while

Tags: java, swing, loop, jbutton

Meu programa tem um loop, criado com o comando `while`. Eu inicio o loop com o botão start.

Porém, eu não consigo fazer mais nada no programa enquanto o `while` está rodando.

Queria colocar um botão chamado Stop que se apertasse nele, ele parasse o programa, tem como fazer?

Ex do código:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    boolean start = true;
    while(start == true){
        System.out.print("Olá");
    }
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    start= false;
}
```

Abaixo a imagem de como fica o botão até acabar o loop:

[image: Botão como se eu tivesse pressionando...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que entender o conceito de thread. O AWT e o Swing rodam em uma thread chamada EDT (veja mais [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/132) e também [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115168/132)). A EDT é reponsável por receber eventos do sistema operacional (mouse, teclado, arrastar janelas, maximizar, minimizar, redesenhar a tela, etc). A EDT também é a thread que responde a eventos, tais como um clique em um botão.

É importante para que a aplicação fique responsiva, nunca sobrecarregar a EDT com tarefas pesadas. Você deve sempre fazer o melhor esforço para que ela fique livre para fazer aquilo que é o propósito dela e nada mais. Ou seja, tarefas como ler ou escrever arquivos, fazer operações complicadas em loop, executar operações em batch, fazer upload ou download de dados na internet, etc de dentro da EDT é uma péssima ideia.

O que ocorre é que você está travando a EDT em um loop infinito. Assim sendo, ela vai ficar presa no loop e não vai ser capaz de processar eventos de redesenhar a tela e nem receber o clique no outro botão. A solução no seu caso é usar uma outra thread para liberar a EDT:

```
private volatile Thread runner;

private void loop() {
    while (runner == Thread.currentThread()) {
        System.out.print("Olá");
    }
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (runner != null) return;
    runner = new Thread(this::loop);
    runner.start();
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    runner = null;
}
```

Comment: Não é melhor trabalhar com [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), que foi feito exatamente para funcionar paralelamente com a EDT, do que criar uma Thread?

Comment: @diegofm Pode ser. Mas neste caso específico, isso não traria nenhuma vantagem, pois o método `done()` não seria necessário e o o `doInBackground()` acabaria com um retorno `Void`. No caso de alguma computação em *background* que produza um resultado final com possíveis resultados intermediários, certamente o `SwingWorker` seria superior, mas não é esse o caso aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, não é uma boa `loops` demorados ou infinitos que nem este no *thread* do `jbutton`. Tente algo assim, em um separado, para sincronizar variáveis entre eles é peculiar:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        // Código aqui
    }
});  
t1.start();
```

Comment: Não é melhor trabalhar com [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), que foi feito exatamente para funcionar paralelamente com a EDT, do que criar uma Thread?