# Como alterar o tamanho das linhas do do grid vertical de uma JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Como faço para alterar o tamanho das linhas do do grid vertical de uma JTable?

Ex:

```
jTable.setRowHeight(30);
```

Este método acima altera  a largura  da  linha.

Tem algum outro semelhante a este que  altere a largura do grid vertical das colunas?

Abaixo uma imagem para ilustrar do que quero alterar a largura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit:

Estou fazendo assim mas mesmo assim não funcionou o que estou fazendo de  errado?

```
public class GuiPrincipal extends JFrame {
    //variaveis para uso da JTable 
    private JTable table;
    private final String colunas[] = {"Nome:", "Idade:", "Sexo:"};
    private final String dados[][] = {
        {"Jack", "19", "Masculino"},
        {"Eddie", "56", "Masculino"},
        {"Gina", "34", "Feminino"},
        {"Klaus", "18", "Masculino"},
        {"Erika", "20", "Feminino"},
        {"Roberto", "29", "Masculino"},
        {"Maria", "30", "Feminino"}};

    /*Construtor da classe ,
          antes de executar o metodo main(),
          irá construir o JFrame e a JTable*/
    public GuiPrincipal() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());//tipo de layout
        setSize(new Dimension(700, 300));//tamanho do Formulario
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);//centralizado
        setTitle("Exemplo JTable");//titulo
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//setando a ação padrão de fechamento do Formulário,
        // neste caso  irá fechar o programa

        //instanciando a JTable
        table = new JTable(dados, colunas);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(700, 300));//barra de rolagem
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //adicionando a tabela em uma barra de rolagem, ficará envolta , pela mesma 
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new Renderer());
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    //este é o método onde é executado nosso programa
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiPrincipal().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

E em baixo a classe de renderer.

```
public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    javax.swing.border.Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50);

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                row, column);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(getBorder(), padding));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou ir na coluna e procurar por setColumnWidth?

Comment: não quero mexer no tamanho da coluna e sim naquele espacinho entre as colunas.

Comment: Não posso ver a imagem, o que você pretende fazer? Não deu pra entender sem ve-la.

Comment: Tem um separador entre as colunas da J table que fica mais ou menos assim    |  coluna1|  coluna2 | .   O que  eu quero é  aumentar  o tamanho desse espaço  para  ele ficar  umas  5 vezes mais largo.Ps: não é  o tamanho da coluna.

Comment: A solucao abaixo nao serviu? Apesar de criar uma borda pra fazer isso, ela meio que "aumenta" esse separador.

Comment: Pelo menos da forma que eu implementei na código acima não teve nenhum resultado.

Comment: De fato, testei e ela realmente nao faz o que voce quer. Vo ver se elaboro algo aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseando-me nas respostas linkadas do SOEn no final deste post, consegui da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer; 
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class GuiPrincipal extends JFrame {
    // variaveis para uso da JTable
    private JTable table;
    private final String colunas[] = { "Nome:", "Idade:", "Sexo:" };
    private final String dados[][] = { { "Jack", "19", "Masculino" }, { "Eddie", "56", "Masculino" },
            { "Gina", "34", "Feminino" }, { "Klaus", "18", "Masculino" }, { "Erika", "20", "Feminino" },
            { "Roberto", "29", "Masculino" }, { "Maria", "30", "Feminino" } };

    /*
     * Construtor da classe , antes de executar o metodo main(), irá construir o
     * JFrame e a JTable
     */
    public GuiPrincipal() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());// tipo de layout
        setSize(new Dimension(700, 300));// tamanho do Formulario
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);// centralizado
        setTitle("Exemplo JTable");// titulo
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// setando a ação padrão de fechamento do Formulário,
        // neste caso irá fechar o programa

        // instanciando a JTable
        table = new JTable(dados, colunas) {

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {

                JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                component.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 0, 2, Color.red));

                return component;
            }
        };

        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0, 0));

        DefaultTableRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

                JComponent comp = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                comp.setBackground(getBackground());
                comp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 0, 2, Color.red));
                return comp;
            }
        };

        table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(renderer);


        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(700, 300));// barra de rolagem
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        // adicionando a tabela em uma barra de rolagem, ficará envolta , pela mesma
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    // este é o método onde é executado nosso programa
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GuiPrincipal().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Mudanças que fiz:

- primeiro alterei como a tabela desenharia as linhas dentro do método [`prepareRenderer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-int-int-), ele é utilizado quando a tabela ainda está sendo construída. Poderia criar um *renderer* e aplicar após a tabela estar criada também, mas desta forma eu acredito ser melhor pois evita o redesenho da tabela.
- dentro do `prepareRenderer()`, defini a nova borda como [`MatteBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/border/MatteBorder.html) pois ela é mais flexível e me deixa definir tanto a cor, quanto a largura de cada borda, separadamente. Assim, defini apenas o tamanho das bordas verticais.
- Não basta apenas personalizar a construção das bordas entre colunas, pois a tabela continuará exibindo o grid mesmo assim. Então, eu desativo as linhas do grid vertical e removo o espaçamento deixado por ele com os métodos [`setShowVerticalLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setShowVerticalLines-boolean-) e [`setIntercellSpacing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setIntercellSpacing-java.awt.Dimension-) respectivamente. Dessa forma, apenas o grid horizontal será exibido.
- As modificações citadas alteram apenas o grid entre células, o cabeçalho da tabela é tratado separadamente. Para alterar ele, eu criei um renderer padrão e aplico a mesma borda dentro deste renderer, e depois aplico a todo o cabeçalho utilizando o `getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(renderer)`.
- Sempre inicie aplicações graficas baseadas na api *swing* dentro da [**event-dispatch-thread**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115168/28595). Os links abaixo podem explicar o porquê se deve fazer assim e quais consequencias se não fizer desta forma:

  - [Por que o método main deve despachar a criação da GUI para a EDT em uma aplicação swing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/28595)
  - [Formas de despachar a interface para a EDT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595)

O resultado final fica assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

**Referências:**

- [Separator between header and data in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25366055/5524514)
- [How to change the GridLine Width of a JTable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29185062/5524514)

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Se você deseja espaçamento dentro da célula, você pode usar uma borda na célula. Observe que você pode usar tamanhos diferentes para esquerda, direita, cima e baixo;

No exemplo o espaçamento foi colocado 10 na esquerda e direita.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer r = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10);
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                row, column);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(getBorder(), padding));
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Não é  nas  bordas é nos separadores das Colunas. Ali onde está apontando a setinha na imagem.

Comment: Ajustada resposta com código completo. Utilize um tablecellrenderer.

Comment: Não funcionou, estou fazendo algo errado.