# Ler arquivo de texto e copiar suas linhas no Clipboard utilizando toolkit

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um arquivo texto(txt) com 1000 linhas, e queria inclui-las no clipboard. Mas dos exemplos que testei, somente a última linha está sendo copiada para o clipboard.

Procurei algo como *apend* para clipboard mas não encontrei.
Como posso fazer isso?

Segue minha tentativa:

```
public class teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("G:\\Arquivos"));
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "text");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);      
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

        int bo = 0;

        while(bo < 1){
            try{
                StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(br2.readLine());
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

            }catch(java.lang.IllegalStateException e){              
                bo = 1;
                br2.close();
                fs.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cade os imports? Como vamos saber os packs dessas classes ai?

Comment: Seria o caso de acumular tudo numa string e fazer o setContents fora do loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplificar utilizando classes do java-7, como a classe [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) que facilita trabalhar com leitura de arquivos de textos, transformando num `List` de strings com as linhas do arquivo. Depois, basta usar um loop para concatenar as linhas com [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html).

Só tome cuidado com o excesso de informações enviadas ao clipboard, não se esqueça de que ele está limitado pela memória do computador e quanto mais dados você enviar, maior será o uso de memória para manter aquele dado disponível.

Também, vale chamar a atenção para alguns pontos que modifiquei que você não está fazendo da maneira correta:

- nunca lance nada para `Throwable`, qual a necessidade? Algumas classes que está usando, de fato, tem exceções checadas, se não quiser tratar, lance a exceção em especifico daquela classe, e não Exception e menos ainda pra essa ai. No caso do código abaixo, eu preferi utilizar [multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), lançar exceção pra frente é o mesmo que "*empurrar o problema com a barriga*",  a não ser que se saiba o que está fazendo e tenha um motivo plausível para isso;
- Você está usando um componente da api java-swing, portanto, é necessário que despache para uma thread especifica, [**chamada EDT**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115168/28595).

O código com as mudanças fica assim:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class LerTxtClipBoardTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("G:\\Arquivos"));
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt");
            fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            try {
                List<String> txtLines = Files.readAllLines(selectedFile.toPath());

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                for (String temp : txtLines) {
                    sb.append(temp);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                }

                StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(sb.toString());
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);


            } catch (IOException | UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Funcionando:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Utilizei um trecho do gerador de texto aleatorios [lorem ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/) para preencher o arquivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou testar

Comment: @vbajr se a resposta lhe ajudou, você pode aceitá-la clicando no `v` ao lado esquerdo. Assim, ela servirá de referencia para outros com problema semelante.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Amigo, Serviu perfeitamente, copiou todas as 5.000 linhas para o clipboard. Valeu mesmo. Sou muito newbie e tenho só noção básica.

Comment: Valeu Articuno L!!!!